What is the name of this late 90's / early 2000's dance TV show
The show was hosted by a tall, white male who had conducted choreography for Britney Spears and other 90s/00s pop stars.
The format featured four dancers who would compete in a 22 minute episode.  Each stage would whittle down one dancer until a single winner emerged.
One of the stages involved stepping onto a platform which would light up and broadcast a dance style or song you had to freestyle to. 
It was broadcast on a cable music channel such as MTV.  The show was named after the host.

Suddenly it came to me:
The Wade Robson Project
http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0356312/

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details for the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
